# Choose file without using browse in android java

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, assign

I have an application on android phone.
People will download pdf file before using my app, and the pdf file will be saved in a certain folder.

I know the absolute path of the folder, but I don't know the name of the new pdf file people download, so I can't get the absolute path of the pdf apparently.

Is there any method to choose the file by using maybe the file type? (Because I am sure that there is only one pdf file in that folder.)
By the way, I don't want to choose file by browse.

Here is the stupid method I used before, but it can't match my demand anymore.

```
public static final String file_name = "//sdcard//Download//test.pdf";
File myFile = new File(file_name);
```

Any easy way to solve the problem?
Thanks for your help sincerely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Getting list of all files of a specific type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015833/android-getting-list-of-all-files-of-a-specific-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below method will give all the PDF files in Download folder.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Download";
File f = new File(path);        
File files[] = f.listFiles();   
for (File f : files)
     {
      String fullPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
      int dot = fullPath.lastIndexOf(".");
      String ext = fullPath.substring(dot + 1);
      if(ext.equals("pdf"))
      {
        //do something with f here
      } 
     }
```